# Get item collection by sku Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection, quoteitem

I try to fetch quote item collection and add some filter like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
$newItem = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection')
          ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$data['quote_id'])
          ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$data['store_id'])
          ->addFieldToFilter('qty',$data['qty'])
          ->addFieldToFilter('sku',$data['sku'])->getFirstItem();
echo "<pre>";print_r($newItem->getData());exit;
```

but i got an error like this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   getStoreId() on null in
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ResourceModel/Quote/Item/Collection.php:98

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the quote item collection must be initialized with an actual quote model to work:

```
$quoteItemCollection->setQuote($quote);
```

This already has been reported as a bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8954

Luckily, to load the collection, it's only needed to retrieve the store id, so you don't need to actually load the quote:

```
$quoteItemCollection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection::class);
$quote = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::class)

$quote->setStoreId($data['store_id']);

$quoteItemCollection
    ->setQuote($quote)
    ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$data['quote_id'])
    ->addFieldToFilter('qty',$data['qty'])
    ->addFieldToFilter('sku',$data['sku']);
$newItem = $quoteItemCollection->getFirstItem();
```

**Note:** Do not use the object manager directly. In real code, `$quoteItemCollection` and `$quote` would be created by factories, which are injected into the class where this code is.

Answer (score 0):

***If you want  a particular quote's item filter then , then you can try below and here i have  loaded quote object then filter the quote  item collection  by this quote***.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$CollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory');
$newItems=$CollectionFactory->create();

/* load quote **/
$quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
$quote = $quoteFactory->create()->load($data['quote_id']);


/* filter Item Collection  by quote */
$newItems
    ->setQuote($quote)
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$data['store_id'])
    ->addFieldToFilter('qty',$data['qty'])
    ->addFieldToFilter('sku',$data['sku']);
$newItem = $newItems->getFirstItem();
echo "<pre>";print_r($newItem->getData('sku'));exit;
```

**Multiple want to filter with multiple quote ids then you should try this:**

```
$resource = $objectManager ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('quote_item');

$query =  $connection->select()->reset()
    ->from(['main_table' => $tableName], '*')
   // ->where('main_table.quote_id = ?',$data['quote_id'])
    ->where('main_table.quote_id IN (?)',array($quoteId1,$quoteId1))
    ->where('main_table.store_id= ?',$data['store_id'])
    ->where('main_table.qty = ?',$data['qty'])
    ->where('main_table.sku= ?',$data['sku'])
    ->limit(0,1) // =  getFirstItem();
    ;

$result = $connection->fetchAll($query);

echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
```